# Set autofocus to an input in html?

Tags: php, html, autofocus

I have some html code and I've heard that autofocus will speed up search results etc. How can I do that with existing code?

I have been looking on other threads etc how to do this and I have tried to understand but I can't if someone could help me out here I would be awesome.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="query" name="query" value="<?php if($this->input->post('query')) { echo $this->input->post('query'); } ?>" placeholder="Search here">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `autofocus` to your input attribute.

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="query" name="query" value="<?php if($this->input->post('query')) { echo $this->input->post('query'); } ?>" placeholder="Search here" autofocus>
```